# How do I retrieve text from an embedded script using casperjs?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

the html element is

```
<script>
window.sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml="<nqw xmlns:saw=\x22com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1\x22 xmlns:xsi=\x22http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\x22 xmlns:sawst=\x22com.siebel.analytics.web/state/v1\x22>\u003csawst:clientState>\u003csawst:stateRef>\u003csawst:envState xmlns:sawst=\"com.siebel.analytics.web/state/v1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlVersion=\"200811100\">\u003csawst:container cid=\"d:dashboard\" xsi:type=\"sawst:topLevelStateContainer\">\u003csawst:container cid=\"p:mco0pb0nob7sqjvg\" xsi:type=\"sawst:page\">\u003csawst:container cid=\"s:42263r43nih80fd1\" xsi:type=\"sawst:section\" rendered=\"true\">\u003csawst:container cid=\"g:c452lvndqssjqa45\" xsi:type=\"sawst:dashprompt\" links=\"-\" promptAutoCompleteState=\"off\"/>\u003c/sawst:container>\u003csawst:container cid=\"r:q4g2fiisnvk4nusv\" xsi:type=\"sawst:report\" links=\"fd\" defaultView=\"compoundView!1\" searchId=\"fvup02s9lt0o6urkplv4pqa5ri\" folder=\"/shared/Sales\" itemName=\"All Sales and Inventory Data\"/>\u003csawst:container cid=\"f:dpstate\" xsi:type=\"sawst:dashpromptstate\" statepoolId=\"ih2bj24l46bkgt558qsef04jeq\"/>\u003csawst:container cid=\"s:b0003tc6gnahvsfq\" xsi:type=\"sawst:section\" rendered=\"true\"/>\u003csawst:container cid=\"s:c5j314uterctfb08\" xsi:type=\"sawst:section\" rendered=\"true\"/>\u003c/sawst:container>\u003c/sawst:container>\u003c/sawst:envState>\u003c/sawst:stateRef>\u003csawst:reportXmlRefferedTo>\u003cref statePath=\"d:dashboard~p:mco0pb0nob7sqjvg~r:q4g2fiisnvk4nusv\" searchID=\"8oh8erup3kcqav10ukp36jaof2\">\u003c/ref>\u003c/sawst:reportXmlRefferedTo>\u003c/sawst:clientState></nqw>";
</script>
```

I want to retrieve the string `ih2bj24l46bkgt558qsef04jeq` under the identifier `statepoolId` from this script section. So how do I find this script in the HTML and get the string using casperjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Accessing `window.sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml`:

This is a script element in a page which adds a variable to the global scope, so you can simply access it through `casper.evaluate`:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml = casper.evaluate(function(){
        return window.sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml;
    });
    // TODO: do something
});
```

#### Doing something with `sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml`:

You could

- do simple string operations to split the string in a more manageable pieces that can be parsed easier by yourself,
- write a Regex matcher to find the specific detail you're looking for, or
- use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the string as XML and then use either [`yourParsedDocument.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`yourParsedDocument.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) to locate the element through CSS selectors or XPath expressions, respectively.

Comment: Does `sawXmlIslandidClientStateXml` contain every script on a single html page?

Comment: No, it just contains the value that you're shown in your question.